# Likelihood Ratio as statistical test for Transfer Entropy with MatLab

Tags: statistical-significance, matlab, entropy, likelihood-ratio

I estimated a Transfer Entropy value TE(XY). Now I want to establish the statistical significance of the estimated value. Therefore I used the method of shuffled surrogates to estimate a shuffled surrogate TEss(XssYss) which should be close to zero because there should be no casual relationship between the shuffled time series. This is my null hypothesis.

Now I want to test the null hypothesis (of zeros TEss) by using the log-likelihood ratio and compute it in MatLab.

I know this is the code in Matlab I should use:

[h,pValue,stat,cValue] = lratiotest(uLL,rLL,dof)

But how do I get the unrestricted and restricted log likelihood maxima supposed TEss
is my result vector of estimated TE using so shuffled time-series. And what are good model parameters?

I appreciate any help:)
Thank you in advance

-klaus